# 'Select method of Worksheet class failed' when trying to select visible cells in DataBodyRange after AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I've used exact same technique in the different module and worked like a charm. I've started new macro with the below code and it fails miserably as soon as trying to `Select` all the filtered cells to make a copy into the template file. It both use `Tables` so `ListObjects`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub ImportMasterData()
    Dim MasterData As Workbook
    Dim Template As Workbook
    
    Dim DateFrom As Date
    Dim DateTo As Date
    
    DateFrom = #2/4/2021#
    DateTo = #6/4/2021#
    
    Set MasterData = Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/RJamborski/Desktop/VBA/Master Archive.xlsx")
    Set Template = Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/RJamborski/Desktop/VBA/MasterArchiveTemplate.xlsx")
    
    With MasterData.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            Array("Dav1 - Danes Way", "Dav2 - Rail Port", "Dav4 - MagnaParkLutterworth"), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & DateFrom, _
            Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & DateTo
    End With
    
    Debug.Print MasterData.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count ' this prints 32106 
    MasterData.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select ' but this throws an error
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Template.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably worth [avoiding Selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in the first place.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?  I think use of special cells requires an unprotected sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the use of `.Select` as Bigben mentioned above. Also it is not necessary that if there are `32106` rows then after filter all of them are visible. You need to try and store the visible range in a range object (Ex: `Set rng = MasterData.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`) by sandwiching this line between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Go To`. After that you have to check `If Not rng is nothing then rng.copy` and then paste it in the destination sheet.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportMasterData()
    Dim MasterData As Workbook
    Dim Template As Workbook
    
    Dim DateFrom As Date
    Dim DateTo As Date
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    DateFrom = #2/4/2021#
    DateTo = #6/4/2021#
    
    Set MasterData = Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/RJamborski/Desktop/VBA/Master Archive.xlsx")
    Set Template = Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/RJamborski/Desktop/VBA/MasterArchiveTemplate.xlsx")
    
    With MasterData.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                    Criteria1:=Array("Dav1 - Danes Way", "Dav2 - Rail Port", _
                    "Dav4 - MagnaParkLutterworth"), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & DateFrom, _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & DateTo
                    
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Copy
        
        Template.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "No Visible range found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked, however I do not understand why I could not select the cells that has been filtered as in the file it was clearly a lot visible cells, but the macro just ignored it?

Comment: There could me many reason for this. Worksheet being protected or hidden or anything that prevents the selection of the cells. And hence it is always better to [Avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)